# Изменить цвет от темы

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Некоторые элементы управления для своих элементов (например: рамки, фона) используют цвет системы, который определятся в зависимости от обоев рабочего стола (сейчас у меня коралловый). Как задать свой цвет?
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: У разных элементов цвет может задаваться по разному, Вас какие элементы интересуют, конкретно?

Comment: RichEditBox, ListView, ToggleButton

Answer (score 1):

Боюсь простого метода, с минимумом усилий,— нет. Придётся брать базовый стиль и исправлять его. К примеру, для `ToggleButton` вот [такой](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/apps/mt299157.aspx) стиль, внутри него идёт выставление `Background` для `Checked` состояния:

```
<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
```

Вам нужно взять стиль и поменять на свои значение то, что Вам нужно. Потом выставлять свой стиль для элемента. И так для всех элементов, которые Вам нужны.

Comment: А SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush не переопределяемый?

Comment: @Monk, глобально — можно, локально — не уверен. Можно попробовать поиграть с ResourceDictionary в code behind, в XAML точно не получится.